# CSVReader is treating multiple lines as one line

Tags: java, file, csv, lines

I am using au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader to read A csv file and print all the records one by one. The code is behaving strange. It's printing some initial lines properly. But, after that it's printing a group of lines together as a single line. Then again it's printing next set of lines correctly. I have checked the CSV file and I find no issues with the file as such.

```
     csvReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileNameWithLocation), ',', '\"', 1);

 ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<DomainObj> mappingStrategy = 
                            new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<DomainObj>();

         mappingStrategy.setType(DomainObj.class);      

          String[] nextLine;

            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) 
            {
                    if (nextLine != null) 
                    log.debug("Next line : " + Arrays.toString(nextLine));
            }
```

And the output is something like :

```
Next line : [Line1 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line2 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line3 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line4 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line5 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line6 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line7 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line8 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line9 from the csv file
             Line10 from the csv file
             Line11 from the csv file
             Line12 from the csv file
             Line13 from the csv file
             Line14 from the csv file
            ]
Next line : [Line15 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line16 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line17 from the csv file]
Next line : [Line18 from the csv file]
```

Comment: Your CSV might be having some issues here. May be some CR/LF characters are missing.

Comment: Yep. Check If you use "\r\n" or "\n" as line end for every line.

Comment: Thank you. But how should I check that?

Comment: I have checked it using an advanced text editor. Both CR and LF characters are present on each line. However, when I print the CSV records using my CSVReader and open that log in the text editor, it shows that CR is removed for these lines. I don't know why.

Comment: Any chance you will be able to upload a sample (2 lines from each set shoulw suffice ) file on dropbox or drive to check ?

Comment: @RamachandranGA A I got the root cause of the issue. The CSV file has double quotes for each field. I observed that on Line9 a text field has \". For e.g. the value of the field is "some text\","Next field". When I removed the back slash (\\) and processed the file , then it worked fine. \ is an escape character, so it's not removing the immediate " while CSVReader is reading the file (observed this in the logs for log.debug("Next line : " + Arrays.toString(nextLine));). Issue is solved, but I don't know how CSVReader identifies when to take the next line in this case?

Comment: @Techidiot Also, currently I have manually removed the backslash, but I would like to know if there's any easy way to programmatically solve this using JAVA only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having trouble configuring the parser with the appropriate format (line endings, escapes, etc). Try [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it can detect the format automatically in most cases, is also 4x faster than opencsv. Try this code:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically();

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
parser.beginParsing(fileNameWithLocation);

String nextLine[];
while ((nextLine = parser.parseNext()) != null){
    //do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this libary. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Comment: Thank you @Jeronimo Backes. I will try this and let you know what happens. Also, would you like to comment on the queries I raised in the 2nd last comment on my question?